# css float, clear problem

Tags: css

I've [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AbFsf/) code.

I gave 15px margin top to `div.loginmeta`, but it hasn't any spaces from top.. why? (if I give a `float:right` to that div, or create a blank div with `clear:both`, it works, but why now it doesn't work? I gave a clear to `div.loginmeta` ...)

Thank you ...

Comment: Can you put this on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yes, here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/AbFsf/

Comment: you should make it clear to us the way you want this stuff to look, make a simple drawing or something

Comment: I can edit the jsFiddle if i would know what you wanted it should look like.

Comment: also, why `float:right;`? in this case it reverses the visual order.

Comment: @adardesign: I want div.loginmeta, has 15px spaced from my form.

Comment: @kikio adardesign means that by floating these elements right, your form reads `"Go" > "password" > "username"`, which is in reverse from the *standard* way (unless this is intended obviously) `Username > Password > Go` makes more semantic sense (at least to LTR users)

Comment: Oh! because it is for RTL users (When I translate it, I did a bad mistake!! :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add `overflow:auto;` to the form you get the desired affect (I believe).

Alternatively float the form element right.

Comment: meanwhile, add overflow: auto to container is better than placing a div with clear:both?

Comment: in my testing it did, at least!

Comment: @kikio yes, `overflow:` is generally seen as the best way (from my experience at least.  The overflow trick eliminates redundant divs in most cases. [more](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2005/02/26/simple-clearing-of-floats/)

Comment: I agree with @Ross answer. You will benefit from learning further about the [clear property](https://kolosek.com/css-clear-float/). The clear property is directly related to the [float property](https://kolosek.com/css-float/). It specifies if an element should be next to the floated elements or if it should move below them.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a workaround, but it works if the margin is made more than, say, 25px.

```
.panel .loginmeta {
    margin-top: 35px;
    font-size: 10px;
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AbFsf/9/ - Have a look.